# Which sentence is more formal?

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, conjunctions, formality

which is better, starting a sentence with a command or giving explanation and then giving the command.

For example, is it better to say:

Do nothing until/till you hear from your boss

OR

Until/Till you hear from your boss, do nothing

Also, which is better for such a sentence, till or until ?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are grammatically both correct with the use of "until".

The difference is in the emphasis - the first part of the sentence is the one which is noticed more, so if this is in a technical instruction context and not an artistic work, I would say that it depends on what the most important thing is: that nothing be done because doing anything could be bad, or that it's important to know who to consult for advice in this situation.

Out of context, it's hard to offer any opinion on that, but in terms of technical instructions, it's not good practice to say what *not* to do, as any negative instructions tend to be ambiguous. I think you should be more specific about what not to do - "don't touch the equipment", "don't speak to anyone about the matter", "don't move from your current position", etc. Surely, you don't expect the reader to stop breathing until the boss tells them to?!

Answer (score 0):

There is not a difference in formality between the two sentences. Though, the latter does put more pressure upon "do nothing", which can be either good or bad. Depends on how you have built the way of speech for the character saying this line. Is he the kind of person putting weight on certain parts of his sentences? As for the second question, *until* **is** more formal than *till*. Some will also write *'till*

Comment: "Some will even write 'till, due to it being a shortened form of until."
 This is completely wrong,
 as [*until*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/until)'s etymology is Old Norse *und* + [*til*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/till) (i.e. the opposite).

Comment: True. I googled it and what I saw was quite fascinating. I'm sorry for my mistake, and I will edit it.

Comment: so which sentence in your opinion is better if there is no difference in formality ? Thank you

Comment: My opinion doesn't matter, since it is a matter of your writing style, and/or the style a certain character speaks in. But, in my opinion, I believe both of them are equally good, and I'd alternate between to two approaches of  sentence construction for good variation in my texts. But again, it's your decision.

Comment: Note: _’till_ is not usually written. _’Til_ is a not-uncommon abbreviation of _until_ (arising from the same misapprehension you originally had that that’s how the word came about), but it’s normally kept separate from _till_.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/should-you-use-until-or-till-or-til